# Подскажите с сортировкой в SQL-запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть не совсем "правильный" sql-запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `quantity` DESC, `position`
```

поле quantity - числовое значение от 0 до нескольких сотен - хранит остаток товара на складе; поле position - внутренняя сортировка товара - чем меньше значение в нем, тем товар должен выводиться в каталоге раньше относительно других.

**Как переписать этот запрос таким образом, чтобы в начале списка шли все товары у которых ненулевое количество на складе (quantity != 0), отсортированные по полю position, а потом товары с нулевым количеством на складе? (если можно это сделать одним запросом)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Используйте [CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html) в предложении ORDER BY.
Примерно так

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY case when `quantity`!=0 then 0 else 1 end, `position`
```

Comment: большое спасибо ) не знал про case, но чувствовал, что есть какое-то простое решение)